# RDS - Why is a backup created on creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

I am working with RDS and I have noticed that when I create the database it seems to create an automated snapshot.

I can understand this when the instance is being shutdown by why is one made when the database is actually created, and is there any way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is RDS doing a backup for you. It defaults to every 30 minutes, but it can be increased up to every 3 hours. You are not able to disable this as it is core functionality for RDS's disaster recovery implementation so that the database can be restored to a 30 minute relative point in time whenever necessary.

Comment: RDS takes one backup per day, but saves all the logs every 5 minutes to support point-in-time restores.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the instance's backup retention period to 0 which will disable backups. However, as far as I know there is no way to create an instance in this state.

RDS uses this snapshot along with the MySQL binary log (or equivalent for other dbs) to provide point in time recovery with 5 minute granularity, as well as restoring the whole snapshot.

Comment: You can create an RDS instance with backups disabled by setting the backup retention to zero. This is not recommended as you would be risking complete data loss.